# Roll, Pitch and Yaw Estimation with Visual Odometry using Monocular Camera

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, slam, visual-odometry

I am currently using OpenCV functions to read a video with the .mp4 extension. This video is from a forward-facing camera on an aerial vehicle. In this video's consecutive frames, I'm detecting keypoints and descriptors. For this purpose, I'm utilizing the ORB detector. I'm detecting keypoints between two frames and finding the transformation matrix. I'm using the knnmatch function for this task. Then, I'm identifying the best matches among these matched keypoints using a threshold. Subsequently, I'm passing these matched keypoints to the estimateAffinePartial2D function to obtain a transformation matrix. From this matrix, I extract the cosine and sine values, which I then input into the atan2 function to calculate the rotation value (the roll angle of the aerial vehicle). When I perform these steps and compare the obtained results with the actual values, I achieve satisfactory outcomes. Now, what I'm looking for from you is guidance on how to use a similar approach to calculate the **pitch and yaw angles** of the aerial vehicle. I would like you to explain the procedure and provide the relevant code.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {
    cv::VideoCapture cap("video.mp4");

    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        std::cout << "Video file not found." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cv::Mat prev_frame, curr_frame;
    cap >> prev_frame;

    cv::Ptr<cv::ORB> orb = cv::ORB::create();
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints_prev, keypoints_curr;
    cv::Mat descriptors_prev, descriptors_curr;

    while (true) {
        cap >> curr_frame;
        if (curr_frame.empty()) {
            break;
        }

        orb->detectAndCompute(prev_frame, cv::noArray(), keypoints_prev, descriptors_prev);
        orb->detectAndCompute(curr_frame, cv::noArray(), keypoints_curr, descriptors_curr);

        cv::BFMatcher matcher(cv::NORM_HAMMING, true);
        std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;
        matcher.match(descriptors_prev, descriptors_curr, matches);

        // 
        std::vector<cv::Point2f> src_pts, dst_pts;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
            src_pts.push_back(keypoints_prev[matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
            dst_pts.push_back(keypoints_curr[matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
        }

**        cv::Mat M = cv::estimateAffinePartial2D(src_pts, dst_pts);**

        // 
**        double roll = std::atan2(M.at<double>(1, 0), M.at<double>(0, 0));
        double pitch = std::atan2(-M.at<double>(1, 2), std::sqrt(M.at<double>(0, 2) * M.at<double>(0, 2) + M.at<double>(2, 2) * M.at<double>(2, 2)));
        double yaw = std::atan2(M.at<double>(0, 2), M.at<double>(2, 2));**

        roll = roll * 180.0 / CV_PI;
        pitch = pitch * 180.0 / CV_PI;
        yaw = yaw * 180.0 / CV_PI;

        std::cout << "Roll: " << roll << " degrees" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Pitch: " << pitch << " degrees" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Yaw: " << yaw << " degrees" << std::endl;

        prev_frame = curr_frame;

        cv::imshow("Current Frame", curr_frame);
        if (cv::waitKey(30) == 27) {
            break;
        }
    }

    cap.release();
    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}
```

The example code provides accurate results for the roll value, but the yaw and pitch values are irrelevant. What approach should I take to address this issue?

As I mentioned earlier, I've tried the steps. While the obtained result accurately estimates the roll value, the yaw and pitch values are incorrectly estimated. It's possible that the mathematical calculations I used for deriving the yaw and pitch values from the transformation matrix could be incorrect.

Comment: Very interesting project. As per the documentation on the OPENCV web page for #cv::estimateAffinePartial2D#: `The function estimates an optimal 2D affine transformation with 4 degrees of freedom limited to combinations of translation, rotation, and uniform scaling. Uses the selected algorithm for robust estimation.`  I think you should be able to use Tx as yaw and Ty as pitch directly. Not sure if you need to do any other compensation on them as per your code.

Comment: But ı have 2D images so ı got keypoints from these images. How can ı get x,y,z rotations?

Comment: Thinking farther about your problem. I think that to be able to do what you are trying to do you should read about: cv::recoverPose(). With the technique you are looking at, you will not be able to find the yaw and pitch directly as you cannot separate rotation in x and y from translation. Using cv::recoverPose should help you do this.